# Does anyone know how to make iPad layout the same as iPhone's? Size wise the text and overall layout get's smaller when I run the app on the iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, layout, interface, responsive

When I run my app on iPhone layout size is fine, texts and everything looks good but when I run the app on iPad text with everything gets really small.
I tried GeometryReader, and custom font options. Overall the iPad screen seems off compare to iPhone, iPhone is bigger.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.